# Programmatically create a complex JSONArray?

Tags: java, json

From what I have read the below example is a `JSONArray`.

I am most confused about adding the top "header" information and the nested "Position" JSONObject as the last property. I know how a basic JSONObject is created, as well as a basic JSONArray, but this combined one is really throwing me off.

```
{
    "source": "REMOTE",
    "msgType": "event",
    "properties": [
        {
            "IMEI": {
                "string": "1234567890"
            }
        },
        {
            "My Time": {
                "string": "5/4/2016 12:00:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "Position": {
                "geographicPosition": {
                    "latitude": 34.89767579999999,
                    "longitude": -72.03648269999997
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's your question that you need answering?

Comment: The above example code is what I need to create. I do not know how to implement it with Java code.

Comment: do you want to create a JSON object using a known implementation or your own?

Comment: In my code I have all the variables that need to go into this array, such as the location and time data. I just do not know how to create this structure as a JSONArray object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
      try {
            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
            mainObject.put("source", "REMOTE");
            mainObject.put("msgType", "event");
            JSONArray mainArray = new JSONArray();

            JSONObject arrayObj = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject temp = new JSONObject();
            temp.put("string", "1234567890");
            arrayObj.put("IMEI", temp);
            mainArray.put(arrayObj);

            arrayObj = new JSONObject();
            temp = new JSONObject();
            temp.put("string", "5/4/2016 12:00:00");
            arrayObj.put("My Time", temp);
            mainArray.put(arrayObj);

            arrayObj = new JSONObject();
            temp = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject temp1 = new JSONObject();
            temp1.put("latitude",34.89767579999999);
            temp1.put("longitude",-72.03648269999997);
            temp.put("geographicPosition", temp1);
            arrayObj.put("Position", temp);
            mainArray.put(arrayObj);

            mainObject.put("properties", mainArray);
            // mainOject is your required Json 
            System.out.println(mainObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It works great, and the structure is very clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this..

```
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json_response);
        String source = jsonObj.getString("source");
        String msgType = jsonObj.getString("msgType");
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("properties");               
        JSONObject IMEIObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject("IMEI");
        String IMEI = IMEIObject.getJSONString("string");
        JSONObject myTimeObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject("My Time");
        String myTime = myTimeObject.getJSONString("string");
        JSONObject posObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject("Position");
        JSONObject lljsonObject = posObject.getJSONObject("geographicPosition");
        String latitude = lljsonObject.getJSONString(String.valueOf("latitude"));
        String longitude = lljsonObject.getJSONString(String.valueOf("longitude"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the great [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html). They have an example that's showing how to create arrays as well. Here's the template they want to create:

```
{
     "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "age": 25,
     "address" : {
         "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
         "city": "New York",
         "state": "NY",
         "postalCode": "10021"
     },
     "phoneNumber": [
         { "type": "home", "number": "212 555-1234" },
         { "type": "fax", "number": "646 555-4567" }
     ]  
}
```

And that's how they do It:

```
\\ You can pass `null` to the `config`
JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory(config);
 JsonObject value = factory.createObjectBuilder()
     .add("firstName", "John")
     .add("lastName", "Smith")
     .add("age", 25)
     .add("address", factory.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("streetAddress", "21 2nd Street")
         .add("city", "New York")
         .add("state", "NY")
         .add("postalCode", "10021"))
     .add("phoneNumber", factory.createArrayBuilder()
         .add(factory.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("type", "home")
             .add("number", "212 555-1234"))
         .add(factory.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("type", "fax")
             .add("number", "646 555-4567")))
     .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. I'll make better efforts.